# Fullcalendar colocar imagem em sql diferentes

Tags: php, fullcalendar

Pessoal tenho um calendário da `API FullCalendar`, ele puxa os eventos do banco, até ai tranquilo, ele puxa direitinho, porém para cada `sql`, pois as informações são de várias tabelas diferentes, eu gostaria de uma imagem diferente. Assim é o que está hoje :

> PHP

```html
$sql = "SELECT id, title, descricao, start, end, color FROM events where responsavel like '%".$LOG_NOME."%'";
//$sql .= ";";
$sql2 = "SELECT TA_ID as id, TA_TAREFA as title, TA_DESCRICAO as descricao, TA_PRAZO as start, TA_PRAZO as end, color FROM db_tarefas WHERE TA_SOLICITADO like '%".$LOG_NOME."%' AND (TA_STATUS = 'NOVA' OR TA_STATUS = 'EM ANDAMENTO')";
//$sql .= ";";
//var_dump($sql);
//echo '<tr><td> '. $FET_ASSISTENCIA["AS_EQUIPE_VIATURA"] . '</td> <td>' . $FET_ASSISTENCIA["AS_EQUIPE_SOCORRISTA"] .'</td><td>'. $FET_ASSISTENCIA["AS_EQUIPE_ENFERMAGEM"] .'</td><td>' . $FET_ASSISTENCIA["AS_EQUIPE_MEDICO"] . '</td>';
$sql3 = "SELECT AS_EQUIPE_VIATURA as viatura, AS_EQUIPE_MEDICO as medico, AS_EQUIPE_SOCORRISTA as socorrista, AS_EQUIPE_ENFERMEIRO as enfermagem, AS_SERVICO_TIPO as tipo, AS_SERVICO_TIPO as tipoS,  AS_ID as id, AS_EMPRESA_NOME as title, AS_PACIENTE_NOME as descricao, AS_EVENTO_FINAL as start, AS_EVENTO_FINAL as end, '#696969' as color FROM db_assistencias WHERE AS_EVENTO_FINAL is not null AND AS_EVENTO_FINAL != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND AS_EXCLUIDO='' ";

$sql4 = "SELECT lans_id as id, lans_id_funcionario as title, lans_id_funcionario as funcionario, lans_id_funcionario as descricao, lans_id_dia as start, lans_id_dia as end, '#696985' as color, extra_subs as extra, lans_valor as valor FROM db_lancamento_substituto WHERE extra_subs = 'SIM'  AND lans_id_dia is not null AND lans_id_dia != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();

//segundo sql
$req2 = $bdd->prepare($sql2);
$req2->execute();
$events2 = $req2->fetchAll();

$req3 = $bdd->prepare($sql3);
$req3->execute();
$events3 = $req3->fetchAll();

$req4 = $bdd->prepare($sql4);
$req4->execute();
$events4 = $req4->fetchAll();

foreach ($events2 as $event2) {
 //$event2['start'] = new DateTime($event2['start']);      
 //$event2['end'] = new DateTime($event2['end']);
 //var_dump($event2['end']);
 array_push($events, $event2);
}

foreach ($events4 as $event4) {
 if($event4['extra'] == 'SIM'){
  if($event4['valor'] == "")
   $event4['color'] = '#FF00FF';
 }
 array_push($events, $event4);
}

foreach ($events3 as $event3) {
 if(($event3['tipo'] == 'EVENTOS') || ($event3['tipoS'] == 'EVENTOS')){
  if($event3['enfermagem'] == "")
   $event3['color'] = '#FF0000';
  if($event3['socorrista'] == "")
   $event3['color'] = '#FF0000';
  if($event3['viatura'] == "")
   $event3['color'] = '#FF0000';
  $viatura = explode("-",$event3['viatura']);
   $SQL_VIATURA = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM db_viaturas where VT_ID = '". $viatura[0] ."'");
   $FET_VIATURA = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL_VIATURA);    
   if($FET_VIATURA['VT_TIPO'] == "USA"){
    if($event3['medico'] == "")
    $event3['color'] = '#FF0000';
   }  
 }
 array_push($events, $event3);
}
```

E aqui é onde troca para a imagem:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.color == "#FF0000") {
                    $(element).find('.fc-content').html('<center><img width="30px" src="../img/vermelha.png" />');
                }else{
                    $(element).find('.fc-content').html('<center><img width="30px" src="../img/cinza.png" />');
                }
                if(event.color == "#FF00FF"){
                    $(element).find('.fc-content').html('<center><img width="30px" src="../img/carinhacinza.png" />');
                }else{
                    $(element).find('.fc-content').html('<center><img width="30px" src="../img/carinhavermelha.png" />');
                }

                element[0].style['cssText'] = "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);";
                $(element).tooltip({title: event.title});

            },
```

O problema está que ele só puxa o primeiro `if`, e não puxa separado, cada `if`.

> No dia 12 ele deveria aparecer o segundo IF que são as carinhas

[image: No dia 12 ele deveria aparecer o segundo IF que são as carinhas]

Alguma sugestão ? Obrigada.

Comment: A função `eventRender` age no objeto `event`. Então, fica mais fácil ajudar se vc puder mostrar a resposta do php, o objeto (ou `array`) retornado.

Comment: editei o comentario, mostrando o que tem no meu php @ShutUpMagda

Comment: Não... Eu falo do objeto `json` que vc está passando para a variável `events` da `fullCalendar`. A resposta da consulta no banco, com o `php`. Exemplo: `[{"title":"Descricao do evento 1","start":"2017-01-11"},{"title":"Descricao do evento 2","start":"2017-01-12"},{"title":"Descricao do evento 3","start":"2017-01-13"}]`.